# tableView numberOfRowsInSection calls tableView viewForHeaderInSection on iOS4

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I got a big app containing a lot of dependencies. For this case I implemented a class called `RootTableViewController` to handle all the stuff that has to be done everytime a table view controller is required.

Now I discovered an endless loop and I dont know how to fix it. I got the following code in `RootTableViewController`:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    int numbersOfRowInSection = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    if (numbersOfRowInSection > 0)
    {
         // ...
    }
    else
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 28.0f)];
        return view;
    }
}
```

This works perfect on iOS 5 and iOS 6, but on iOS4 it causes an endless loop, because `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection]` is calling `[tableView viewForHeaderInSection]`. How can I fix this using the table view api? Its no solution for me to work with the `[ count]` of internal data arrays because I got a lot of table view controllers extending this `RootTableViewController` with different data sources.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not good style. You are supposed to subclass or rahter implement the related delegate method but you shoudl not call `UITableView.numberofRowsInSection:`

However, you have certainly implemented `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`. Move all of its functionality to the new method `myNumberOfRowsInSection:` In there do the same. It is mainly a copy of your current `numberOfRowsInSection`. 
Then here in your code sniplet call `[self myNumberOfRowsInSection:...];`

And within `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:section` just do:

```
return [self myNumberOfRowsInSection:section];
```

Apply the same pattern to all delegate methods that you may want to call yourself. Move all its business logic into your own method and then only call your own method from the delegate method and from your own code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of rows in a section of the data source without accessing the internal data array, you could query the `dataSource` delegate for it, something like

```
int numbersOfRowInSection = [self.tableView.dataSource tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
```

(not compiler checked)

Comment: That will work. In most cases self.talbeView.dataSource and self.tableView.delegate will point to self anyway :)